# Cannot bulid react-native init

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

I have big problem when I tried to build my new react-native project and I don't know why. Pls help, thank you so much!!

```
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha512-WIr7iDkdmdbxu/Gh6eKEZJL6KPE74/5MEsf2whTOFNxbIoIixogroLdKYqB6FDav4Wavh/lZdzzd3b2K    xIXC5Q== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha
512-WIr7iDkdmdbxu/Gh6eKEZJL6KPE74/5MEsf2whTOFNxbIoIixogroLdKYqB6FDav4Wavh/lZdzzd
3b2KxIXC5Q== but got sha512-gr+uDP+o1V+q1lQw6M4IsLwOk8XutOi1VWiA7186M4O1v3Brs19R
pweK4XDKlY4xAtFrtJ+QHnxIzUDFCqb/mQ==. (887 bytes)
npm WARN tar invalid entry

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\**Name**\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-11-17T09_35_58_618Z-debug.log
{ Error: Command failed: npm install --save --save-exact react-native
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:574:11)
    at execSync (child_process.js:611:13)
    at run (C:\Users\**Name**\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:294:5)
    at createProject (C:\Users\**Name**\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:249:3)
    at init (C:\Users\**Name**\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:200:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\**Name**\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:153:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:641:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:652:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:560:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:503:12)
  status: 1,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 7416,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null }
Command `npm install --save --save-exact react-native` failed.
```

Comment: Try `npm cache clean --force` and, if there, delete the `package-lock.json` file. Then just run your command again.

Comment: Thx. but it not working T T

Comment: does created project working fine or you get error doing that ?